# Legendary visits by Alexander the Great

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, alexander-the-great

There is a [story](http://www.livius.org/aj-al/alexander/alexander_t35.html) about Alexander the Great visiting Jerusalem. This story is not supported by other sources, as far as I know, and so is probably not literally true (it may well reflect some interaction short of a visit). I also recall reading (in an old Cambridge volume, I think) about a Greek city (possibly on the shores of the Black Sea) which had a legend about Alexander visiting it and reforming its laws - once again, the visit being practically impossible given what we know about Alexander's itinerary and schedule.

Are there other examples? I am asking about legends recorded in antiquity, not the numerous highly imaginative medieval stories about Alexander.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you really hoping to determine?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I think I have com e upon a curious parallel and am wondering if it's a pattern or not.

Comment: OK. That comment doesn't give me much to work with though does it? I think you will have to be less coy in order to let us focus appropriately.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Actually, there is no hidden agenda or ulterior motive. I've always thought that the way Josephus embellished the Jewish-Alexandrian dynamic was just part of the ancient tradition of Jewish apology (such as the pseudo-Aristaeus letter). But when I came across the other story, I began to wonder whether Josephus was not also following a Greek literary tradition of ascribing laws to Alexander. Not being a professional historian or classical phylologist, I am just speculating here, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

Jerusalem being the capital of a province of his empire, that he passed by at least twice going to and returning from Egypt, it seems most unlikely that Alexander **didn't** visit Jerusalem. He apparently went out of his way to visit the [Siwa Oasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siwa_Oasis) (where his god-hood was confirmed) after founding Alexandria.

[Chapter Eight of Volume XI](http://www.ccel.org/j/josephus/works/ant-11.htm) of Josephus describes the entry of Alexander into Jerusalem in somewhat fantastic terms, but there doesn't seem an obvious reason why this would be manufactured.

> .... And when the Book of Daniel was showed him [Alexander] wherein Daniel declared that one of the Greeks should destroy the empire of the Persians, he supposed that himself was the person intended. And as he was then glad, he dismissed the multitude for the present; but the next day he called them to him, and bid them ask what favors they pleased of him; whereupon the high priest desired that they might enjoy the laws of their forefathers, and might pay no tribute on the seventh year. He granted all they desired. ....

Felix Goldberg below raises good points about the veracity of Josephus' story above.

However:

1. Compared to visiting the Siwa Oasis - 10-14 days travel due south into the Libyan desert, don't get lost in that featureless waste or you die - a quick jaunt from Gaza to Jerusalem is nothing.
2. Alexander was vain - he seems to go anywhere, and do anything, to have his divine destiny to overthrow the Persians reaffirmed. As evidence, note point (1) above.

Certainly the story by Josephus is fanciful, and undoubtedly exaggerated in its details; but I still see no reason to doubt it's core, given Alexander's demonstrated vanity for this sort of attention. Just a whisper in his ear that the Jews had a holy book in a great temple foretelling a Greek defeating the Persians, and I think he would have postponed even a battle to visit in person.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about this answer. While it is good to confute a wrong assumption the OP had, it still lacks any info about the actual question, i.e. if there are instances of cities pretending to be visited by Alexander.

This would be _very_ good as a _partial_ answer, along the lines of _"those cities claim to have been visited by Alexander, but they weren't; however he did actually visited Jerusalem, instead"_

Comment: @Lohoris: I hear you; however list questions are explicitly off-topic for the site, so the only portion of the question that seems to actually be on-topic, at this moment, is in regards to whether Alexander visited Jerusalem.

Comment: Sure, but we shouldn't take that rule blindly. The purpose of disallowing list questions is for answers who risk becoming a huge unmanageble (hence unhelpful) list, while here likely it would be a "list" of just a few cities. If I asked you which nations were allied with UK during WWI would you consider it a list question? (disregarding the fact that it's trivial anyway)

Comment: @Lohoris: It would be a list question, and might be less trivial than you think. It changed over the course of the war, so one must first determine which date is of interest. I certainly could not manufacture this list off the top of my head: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participants_in_World_War_II

Comment: @Lohoris What is the wrong assumption in my question?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg You assumed he didn't actually go there, while, **according to this answer**, he instead did. _(but this answer fails to actually answer the question fully)_

Comment: @Lohoris Well, have you considered the possibility the answer itself may be wrong?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: That is always possible - what evidence do we have for doubting Josephus? There is circumstantial evidence that lends him credence.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I don't get your point. My point is that _if_ this answer is right, it still is only a partial and not a full answer. I'm not arguing about what's there, I'm arguing about what isn't there. Frankly I have no clue about why are you attacking me, wtf?

Comment: Dear Pieter, your answer is al always knowledgeable and well-reasoned but I do think you've got it wrong this time. I'll try to explain why: (a) I am familiar with Josephus's story; indeed if you click on the hyperlink in the question you'll find that it leads to a scholarly discussion of it! The first sentence is: "Most scholars agree that the following story [...] is not true". (b) livius.org really goes into the detail of the arguments fuller and better than I could do here. (c) however, livius.org does list some oddities in the story that make it unlikely it was spun out of whole cloth

Comment: - rather, it is probably [my surmise now] a reflection of what I had called "some interaction short of a visit". (d) Judea was quite a backwater and I don't think Alexander ever had a habit of visiting *every* provincial capital. (e) It is true Alexander passed in the area twice but I think that he would have found it easier and faster to go by the coastal road than to make a detour into the mountainous area of Jerusalem, unless he had a really good reason for doing so.

Comment: @Lohoris I am not attacking you. Really sorry if it came across that way! I am just trying to point out that you're jumping to conclusion a tad too quickly in this case - probably bacuase you haven't had the chance to look at the source I linked to - it discusses the Josephus source that Pieter mentions and explains why it is a very problematic one. So it's somewhat premature to assume my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Lohoris Okay, never mind.